# MySQL Structure for natural language processing

Tags: mysql, database, nlp

I want to create a question / answer MySQL DB in which questions and their matching answers are stored. The user should be able to enter questions in natural language based on which the most fitting stored question is searched and the matching answer is displayed. Since I don't want to make my life more difficult than needed I would like to get some input on how to best structure the DB for such an application. Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use match() with if condition in select query. like below :

```
SELECT IF(MATCH (questionfieldname) AGAINST ('questiontext' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE), answerfieldname, NULL) as answer FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Just remember: There must be no explicit ORDER BY clause